# Markov-type inequalities with arbitrary exponents

Tags: approximation-theory, polynomials, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

By a Markov-type inequality I mean an inequality of the form
$$
\| p^{(k)} \| \leq \lambda_{k,n} \| p \|,\quad \forall p \in U_n,
$$
for some $\lambda_{k,n} > 0$, where $U_n \subset L^\infty[-1,1]$ is a subspace of dimension $n$ and
$$
\| g \| = \sup_{x \in [-1,1]} | g(x) |.
$$
If $U_n$ is the space of algebraic polynomials of degree $n$, then it is well known that
$$
\lambda_{k,n} = O(n^{2k}),\quad n \rightarrow \infty,
$$
for each fixed $k$, whereas for trigonometric polynomials,
$$
\lambda_{k,n} = O(n^{k}),\quad n \rightarrow \infty.
$$
My question is as follows.  Is it possible to find subspaces $U_1 \subset U_2 \subset U_3,\ldots$ with $\bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1} U_n$ dense in $L^\infty[-1,1]$ possessing Markov-type inequalities with arbitrary exponents, i.e.
$$
\lambda_{k,n} = O(n^{\alpha k}),\quad n \rightarrow \infty,
$$
for some given $\alpha > 0$?  Moreover can one find such subspaces in a constructive manner?

Comment: No. We must have $\alpha\ge 1$ at the very least. Indeed, assume that $\|f'\|\le \lambda \|f\|$ for every $f\in U_{n+1}$. Choose a non-zero $f$ orthogonal to all characteristic functions of intervals $I_k=[\frac kn,\frac{k+1}n]$. Then $\|f\|\le \max_k\operatorname{osc_{I_k}}f\le \frac 1n\|f'\|\le \frac{\lambda}n\|f\|$, so $\lambda n\ge 1$.

Comment: Sorry, the last inequality should read $\lambda\ge n$.

Comment: Thanks.  However, I should have said that it's the case $\alpha \geq 1$ that's of interest.

Comment: Then $\sin [k^\alpha] x$ is such a system ($U_n$ is the span of the first $n$ functions). 

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  However, your construction doesn't work when you require $\cup U_n$ to be dense in $L^\infty[-1,1]$.  Apologies, I should have added this to the original question  - have now changed it accordingly.

Comment: If you want density, just add first $n$ functions in the standard trigonometric system to $U_n$ and reenumerate accordingly.